# Parsing date from file name in regexp

Tags: python, regex

I've got a file that can be named something like `wh-201310301615.tar.gz` but it will always have the `-201310301615.tar.gz` part. I want to find if that string is in the file name and get only the numbers (thus `-` and `.tar.gz` mus be present). Currently I use next pattern to find it:

```
-\d+\.tar\.gz
```

but I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it and to get only the numbers (currently I have to trim the string). Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:I'm using python thus it's engine.

Comment: What language/flavor are you using ? You will need lookaround assertions

Comment: @DenysS. Are you using unix tool for this parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern.

```
(?<=-)(\d+)(?=\.tar\.gz)
```

see **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wO6iT1)**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what regex engine you are using, but assuming I've understood your question, this should work in any that support lookarounds.

```
(?![^-]+-)\d+(?=\.tar\.gz)
```

Comment: Your solution is also good, but the lookbehind part includes a redundant check not (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a find and a small script.

```
unix> ls
wh-201310301615.tar.gz
wh-201310301616.tar.gz

unix> find . -name "wh-*.tar.gz" -exec find_it {} \;
201310301615
201310301616

unix> cat find_it
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 | cut -c 6-17
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work since I wh part can change. And I need only one script/command.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Replacing 'wh' with '??' would do it, but I see that you already have something that works.

Comment: Yeah well you're suggesting how to place regexp into a find command not how to form the actual regexp. That's mainly why it doesn't work. ;) Thanks nevertheless.